# Referencing knockout array from outside of databind and without path knowledge

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, data-binding

I've ran into a few issues while developing a webapp. There is a need to access knockout.js's array used in a `foreach` binding from outside of knockout, or rather in .js files. Now `ko.dataFor()` and `ko.contextFor()` allow me to access the context and data for a specific element of an array, but not the array itself.

What i basically need is the ability to scan the entire array (all elements) for a value of one of the properties and send all the present ones to the server via AJAX when making a request in order to 'filter out' the ones that are already present, making it unique selector over multiple array entries, if that makes any sense.

I am pretty sure that the answer lies somewhere in the aforementioned functions I just cannot seem to find it.

### Edit:

The external script needs to either access the observable array which holds the elements used for binding, or get informed of a path to that array starting from the root of the view model. I cannot use `subscribe` to get the info on the data because I do not know what to subscribe to. A model is dynamic and the `example array` in this case is nested 3 levels deep if it is even there. It is also in a loop itself thus the path to it varies based on which html element is accessed as in, it might be indexed differently in the parent's loop. The only entry point i have is the element that is bound.

**Check the example for a better understanding.**

```js
var VM = {};
var data = {
  exampleArray: [{
      key: 1,
      value: 'foo1'
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: 'foo2'
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      value: 'foo3'
    }
  ],
  lookup: [{
      key: 1,
      value: 'foo1'
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: 'foo2'
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      value: 'foo3'
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      value: 'foo4'
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      value: 'foo5'
    }
  ]
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, VM);
ko.applyBindings(VM);

function addRow() {
  var select = document.getElementById('selector');
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  VM.exampleArray.push({
    key: ko.observable(value),
    value: ko.observable(text),
  })
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#container>div {
  border: solid 1px green;
  min-height: 15px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}
select {
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach: exampleArray">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: key() + ' - '"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<select id="selector" data-bind="options: lookup,
                       optionsText: 'value',
                       optionsValue: 'key'
                       "></select>
<button onclick="addRow();">Add a row</button>

<p> Now imagine that the lookup data set is updated from the server via AJAX call every time a row is added, where it would need to send only the rows that are not already present in this data set, making this a unique selection. I would need a way to send keys already selected to the server, so that SQL can filter out what data to send back and what data to skip. <br><br>

<b>How would i get this information?</b><br><br>

P.S. I need a way to send an array of keys, not the whole model or data-set or whatever inventive solution might be, because this is an oversimplifed example, the real model is deep nested and much more complex, and pretty much inaccessible/untouchable in the heirarchy of the app's classes that make it. If you need clerification as to why, post a comment and I will try to answer as briefly as possible.</p>
```

### **SPECIAL EDIT:**

```js
var VM = {};
var data = {
  some: {
    super: [
      {
        deep: {
          nested: {
            shit: {
              articles: [
                {key: 1, value: "fish"},
                {key: 2, value: "fruit"},
                {key: 3, value: "meat"},
              ],    
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    lookup: [
      {key: 1, value: "fish"},
      {key: 2, value: "fruit"},
      {key: 3, value: "meat"},
      {key: 4, value: "eggs"},
      {key: 5, value: "bread"},
      {key: 6, value: "milk"},
      {key: 7, value: "water"},
    ]
  }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, VM);
ko.applyBindings(VM);

document.getElementById('sayt').addEventListener('focus', function(){
  document.getElementById('saytResults').style.display = "block";
})
document.getElementById('sayt').addEventListener('blur', function(){
  document.getElementById('saytResults').style.display = "none";
})

function printListItemContextData(btn){
  console.log(ko.contextFor(btn.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('selectedArticles')[0].children[0]));
}
```

```css
#sayt, #saytResults{
  width: 200px;
}
#saytResults > div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: some.super">
  <div class="selectedArticles" data-bind="foreach: deep.nested.shit.articles">
    <div data-bind="text: key() + ' - ' + value()"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Imagine that the input control below is a "full text search" of the articles on the database. As you type, a request is sent to the server with your typed text as a parameter for the query, results get delivered into the lookup dataset.</p>
  
  <input id="sayt" type="text" value="Click here to simulate request">
  <div id="saytResults" style="display: none;" data-bind="foreach: $root.some.lookup">
    <div data-bind="text: key() + ' - ' + value()"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>
  The goal however is to NOT display elements that are already present in the dataset. But I cannot get to that data set, I have no idea how to "target" the array. The button below can 'print' the info (console.log) of any of the elements already in the list, but not the list itself.
  </p>
  <button onclick="printListItemContextData(this)"> PRINT </button>
  <p>The issue is, parent context is not created as you go deep down the tree, and $parent of an element of a <b>foreach</b> is not the array it is in, but rather an object, 3 levels up.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, which DOM element do you have access to, and which data object do you need to be able to reach from it?

Comment: @RoyJ My example is not an accurate representation of what element i have access to, because the element that I am using is a custom made control. 

I will update the question in regard to this comment to further explain, I feel that the info provided thus far might not be detailed enough to grasp the true problem, I will create a new example and update, but give me some time, in the middle of some other work at the moment. Will tag you once done.

Comment: @RoyJ took a while, been busy on another task. I edited the example to be more 'alike' to the issue at hand, take a look if it still peeks your interests. I think that it is possible to access the needed info under contract that as you traverse the dom representation of the model, `with` binding is always used on every container on a lower level in order to avoid skipping, i see no other way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your data is an array and also that there's one child DOM node per element of the array, you can reconstruct the array by iterating the child nodes and getting the `dataFor` from each. The attached snippet does that.

Update: tweaked code so it doesn't matter how many child nodes per element there are.

```js
var VM = {};
var data = {
  some: {
    super: [
      {
        deep: {
          nested: {
            shit: {
              articles: [
                {key: 1, value: "fish"},
                {key: 2, value: "fruit"},
                {key: 3, value: "meat"},
              ],    
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    lookup: [
      {key: 1, value: "fish"},
      {key: 2, value: "fruit"},
      {key: 3, value: "meat"},
      {key: 4, value: "eggs"},
      {key: 5, value: "bread"},
      {key: 6, value: "milk"},
      {key: 7, value: "water"},
    ]
  }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, VM);
ko.applyBindings(VM);

document.getElementById('sayt').addEventListener('focus', function(){
  document.getElementById('saytResults').style.display = "block";
})
document.getElementById('sayt').addEventListener('blur', function(){
  document.getElementById('saytResults').style.display = "none";
})

function printListItemContextData(btn){
  const el = btn.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('selectedArticles')[0];
  const data = [];
  
  for (const c of el.children) {
    data[ko.contextFor(c).$index()] = ko.dataFor(c);
  }
  
  console.log("Data:", ko.toJS(data));
}
```

```css
#sayt, #saytResults{
  width: 200px;
}
#saytResults > div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: some.super">
  <div class="selectedArticles" data-bind="foreach: deep.nested.shit.articles">
    <div data-bind="text: key() + ' - ' + value()"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Imagine that the input control below is a "full text search" of the articles on the database. As you type, a request is sent to the server with your typed text as a parameter for the query, results get delivered into the lookup dataset.</p>
  
  <input id="sayt" type="text" value="Click here to simulate request">
  <div id="saytResults" style="display: none;" data-bind="foreach: $root.some.lookup">
    <div data-bind="text: key() + ' - ' + value()"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>
  The goal however is to NOT display elements that are already present in the dataset. But I cannot get to that data set, I have no idea how to "target" the array. The button below can 'print' the info (console.log) of any of the elements already in the list, but not the list itself.
  </p>
  <button onclick="printListItemContextData(this)"> PRINT </button>
  <p>The issue is, parent context is not created as you go deep down the tree, and $parent of an element of a <b>foreach</b> is not the array it is in, but rather an object, 3 levels up.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Way to think outside of the box! Accepted. Thanks

Comment: I also have to say, that it would be great if this thing could get abstracted and only work on data, but if there is no way, your method solves the issue